# React javascript two arrays of objects,I want to find and filter by key, and the result of this, I want to count by another key

Tags: arrays, reactjs, object, if-statement, find

I have two arrays of objects ( `resultsSchoolsRegion` and `infoCovBySchool`). There is a commun key (`codi_centre` and `codcentre`). I need to find and filter in `infoCovBySchool` all the `resultsSchoolsRegion` match by `codcentre`.
After find and filter, with those results I want to count all the schools by key `estat === 'Confinat'` . I have an error "Cannot read property 'estat' of undefined"

MY CODE

```
const resultsSchoolsRegion = [
  {
    codi_centre: "43000433",
    denominaci_completa: "Escola Sant Miquel",
    adre_a: "c. Sant Miquel, s/n"
  },
  {
    codi_centre: "43000561",
    denominaci_completa: "Escola Antoni Nat - ZER Benissanet-Miravet",
    adre_a: "c. Reus, s/n"
  },
  {
    codi_centre: "43001280",
    denominaci_completa: "Escola Pàmies - ZER La Font de l'Aiguadí",
    adre_a: "c. Riu, 9"
  },
  {
    codi_centre: "43001681",
    denominaci_completa: "Escola Lluís Viñas i Viñoles",
    adre_a: "c. Mestres, 7"
  },
  {
    codi_centre: "43005479",
    denominaci_completa: "Escola 1 d'Abril - ZER Ebre",
    adre_a: "c. Major, s/n"
  },
  {
    codi_centre: "43011248",
    denominaci_completa: "Llar d'infants La Morera",
    adre_a: "c. Santiago Rusiñol, 22"
  },
  {
    codi_centre: "43011972",
    denominaci_completa: "Llar d'infants La Torre de l'Espanyol",
    adre_a: "c. de l'Era, s/n"
  },
  {
    codi_centre: "43012630",
    denominaci_completa: "Llar d'infants Els Figotets",
    adre_a: "c. Reus, 3"
  }
];

const infoCovBySchool = [
  {
    codcentre: "43000433",
    estat: "Obert",
    grup_confin: "0"
  },
  {
    codcentre: "43000561",
    estat: "Obert",
    grup_confin: "0"
  },
  {
    codcentre: "43001280",
    estat: "Obert",
    grup_confin: "0"
  },
  {
    codcentre: "43001681",
    estat: "Obert",
    grup_confin: "0"
  },
  {
    codcentre: "43005479",
    estat: "Confinat",
    grup_confin: "0"
  }
];

const api = {
  async getInfoMapSchoolsRegions(query) {
    try {
      let totalCovidRegion = 0;
      resultsSchoolsRegion.map(school => {
        let filterResults = infoCovBySchool.find(item => {
          return item.codcentre === school.codi_centre;
        });

        if (
          filterResults.estat !== undefined &&
          filterResults.estat === "Confinat"
        ) {
          totalCovidRegion += 1;
        }
      });
      return { totalCovidRegion };
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
  }
};
export default api;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some cases the `infoCovBySchool.find(...)` function doesn't find a matching school. In that case `filterResults` is `undefined`.

In your `estat`-check you are checking whether `filterResults.estat`is `undefined`. But as `filterResults` itself is already `undefined`, the code can't access the property `estat`.

Your fix is therefore to check for `filterResults !== undefined` instead.

Here would be the full function:

```
const api = {
  async getInfoMapSchoolsRegions(query) {
    try {
      let totalCovidRegion = 0;
      resultsSchoolsRegion.map((school) => {
        let filterResults = infoCovBySchool.find((item) => {
          return item.codcentre === school.codi_centre;
        });
        if (filterResults !== undefined && filterResults.estat === "Confinat") {
          totalCovidRegion += 1;
        }
      });
      return { totalCovidRegion };
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
  },
};
```